# Date of answer earlier than question

Tags: bug

Question

[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Network Manager cannot add VPN - greyed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902930/ubuntu-16-04-lts-network-manager-cannot-add-vpn-greyed-out)

is dated as "asked Apr 9 '17 at 17:52".

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/877331/226614) is dated as "answered Jan 28 '17 at 20:50".

**How can this be understood?**
**Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was merged from this question asked in 2016
[How to add a VPN connection in Ubuntu 16.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840961/how-to-add-a-vpn-connection-in-ubuntu-16-10)

So as confusing as this may be, it is correct, the answer was written to antother question before the one in question existed and then moved later.

You can see this in the revision history https://askubuntu.com/posts/877331/revisions